# Firebase Database (${JSCORE_VERSION}) INTERNAL ASSERT FAILED: Reference.ts has not been loaded. in angular 6 application

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular6, angularfire2

I am working on angular 6 latest version. I install [angularfire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2) for database. Its working fine. But on IE9 and IE10 show error.

```
Firebase Database (${JSCORE_VERSION}) INTERNAL ASSERT FAILED: Reference.ts has not been loaded
```

**Version-**

```
"@angular/fire": "^5.0.2"

"firebase": "^5.5.2",
```

Please tell me how to solve is error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to post your code, but clearly the file Reference.ts cannot be loaded.

By default AngularFire uses src/environment/environment.ts for the firebase DB information

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  firebase : {
    apiKey: "xxxx",
    authDomain: "xxx.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://xxx.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "xxx",
    storageBucket: "xxx.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "xxx"
 }


};
```

You would then reference this in src/app/app.modules.ts

```
  imports: [
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
```

Comment: can you post all your code on the .ts component please